# Entity Framework install troubles

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When runing `$ dotnet restore` after adding

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.2.0"/>
</ItemGroup>`
```

to `DBCreation.csproj`
(both manualy or by NuGet) nothing occurs, just finishing with

```
Restoring packages for /home/denis/Documents/projects/dotNet/DBCreation/DBCreation.csproj...
```

and `Entity` in `using System.Data.Entity;` is still marked

```
"The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [DBCreation]"
```

When trying to run this (just Hello world! with this using):

```
$dotnet run 
The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.
```

but

```
$ dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.6.84.34536 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Restoring packages for 
/home/denis/Documents/projects/dotNet/DBCreation/DBCreation.csproj...
```

finishes like `restore`, without showing errors.

When there isn't EntityFramework in .csproj list restoring finishes like

```
Restoring packages for /home/denis/Documents/projects/dotNet/DBCreation/DBCreation.csproj...
Restore completed in 751.55 ms for /home/denis/Documents/projects/dotNet/DBCreation/DBCreation.csproj.
```

and working correct.

I'm using Visual Studio Code on Debian 9.

```
$ dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (2.1.105)

Product Information:
Version:            2.1.105
Commit SHA-1 hash:  141cc8d976

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     debian
OS Version:  9
OS Platform: Linux
RID:         debian.9-x64
Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.105/

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

Version  : 2.0.7
Build    : 2d61d0b043915bc948ebf98836fefe9ba942be11
```

*How to add Entity Framework to project, what is wrong with restore and where is my mistake?*

Comment: Make sure to target .Net Framework when using EF 6.2.0. It seems like you're not use the good  target.

Comment: If you are looking for using EF Core so you are not using the good one. EF 6.2.0 is for target the .Net Framework and not the .Net Core.

Comment: @CodeNotFound, this was just first one in list; what I should use instead of this?

Comment: If you're targeting `netcore` or `netstandard` target frameworks (found in your csproj under the `<targetframework>` tag) you'll want to use the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/), then, assuming you are using MSSQL, you'll also need the [Relational](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/2.1.0-rc1-final) and [SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/2.1.0-rc1-final) packages.

Comment: You shoudl use EF Core  (not EF) when target .Net Core => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/#pivot=efcore

Comment: @CodeNotFound, my cspoj targeting `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>`
and now I'm trying to use EF Core:
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.3"/>`
`<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2"/>`

thats `restore` results like previous one (`Restoring packages for /home/denis/Documents/projects/dotNet/DBCreation/DBCreation.csproj...`) with no result. 

Newtonsoft.Json and other packages restore without these completes by `Restore completed in 434.52 ms for ...csproj.` and works fine.